# Make Python libraries installed with requirements.txt immediately available

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

Here's a very simple requirements.txt:

```
numpy
sharedmem
```

The problem is, sharedmem actually [depends on having numpy available to even run its setup.py](https://github.com/rainwoodman/sharedmem/blob/master/setup.py#L1), it's an install dependency. Running `pip install -r requirements.txt` does try to install numpy first, as expected, but sharedmem still breaks on trying to import `numpy.distutils.core`. Presumably because pip installs libraries into a temporary build directory first and it's not in the import path.

Any ideas on how to deal with it?

P.S. Looks like this is a dupe: [In Python, `pip -r requirements.txt` doesn't install packages *recursively*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063522/in-python-pip-r-requirements-txt-doesnt-install-packages-recursively), but the problem wasn't resolved there either.

Comment: That kind of looks like the fault of `sharedmem`'s `setup.py` to me.  We should not import dependencies since they may not be there yet, causing exactly the breakage you are seeing ..

Comment: Yes, sharedmem happens to not actually need those imports (as far as I see), but the problem is more general: there are packages that depend on others for setup.py to run, it's a legitimate requirement.

Comment: Oh, it actually does use numpy's specific version of `setup()`. But I don't know if it actually needs it.

Comment: Same happens with cloudflare-1.1.5. They use "requests" in setup, and it doesn't work in a single "install -r requirements", even though "requests" is in requirements of cloudflare, and even specified explicitly in requirements.txt before cloudflare. Workaround is to setup dependency by a separate install cmd :(